# can #+BIND: be wrapped?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Correct Version:

```
#+BIND: org-html-postamble-format (("en" "abcxyz"))
```

but if the format string is very long, is there a way to wrap it to multilines?

something like this:

```
#+BIND: org-html-postamble-format (("en" "abc ~
# xyz"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no.  Keywords in org-mode are constrained to a single line and there is no wrapping character.  If you feel strongly about your line length you might consider:

1. Using the `#+SETUPFILE` mechanism (see: [In-buffer settings](http://orgmode.org/manual/In_002dbuffer-settings.html))
2. Defining that format in your dotemacs file so you can span multiple lines.
3. Using some form of local [file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables) or [directory](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html#Directory-Variables) variables.  For example local variables may span multiple lines:

```
# Local Variables:
# eval: (setq org-html-postamble t)
# eval: (setq org-html-postamble-format '(("en" "foo
# bar \
# baz")))
# End:
```

**Note:** You may notice that some some particular keywords have "wrapping" behavior such as node properties (http://orgmode.org/manual/Property-syntax.html):

```
 #+PROPERTY: var  foo=1
 #+PROPERTY: var+ bar=2
```

Behavior like this is special and limited to those keywords.  No equivalent wrapping behavior exists for the `BIND` keyword.

*Current org-mode version (as of this post): 8.3.4*